# File type association of an air application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I am creating an air application which shows the path of a file when the file is dropped into the application icon. Works great in windows but in Mac the application icon do not accept any file to be dropped over it. So for testing I registered a .txt file to the application using application descriptor

```
        <!-- The name that the system displays for the registered file type. Required. -->
        <name>myAIREditor.Text</name>

        <!-- The extension to register. Required. -->
        <extension>txt</extension>

        <!-- The description of the file type. Optional. -->
        <description>myAIREditor text description file</description>

        <!-- The MIME content type. -->
        <contentType>text/plain</contentType>

        <!-- The icon to display for the file type. Optional. -->
        <!-- <icon>
            <image16x16></image16x16>
            <image32x32></image32x32>
            <image48x48></image48x48>
            <image128x128></image128x128>
        </icon> -->

    </fileType>
```

and alas, text files can be dropped over the application icon and it shows the path. Now do I have to do it for all of 10 billion file types?

Is there a way so that I can tell my app to accept any kind of file no matter what the extension is?

Answer (score 0):

Without saying how you're handing a drag in/drop exactly then it's impossible to offer assistance.

Try checking out [this helpful document](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7d83.html) to see if it applies to your situation.

Comment: I am invoking the application using

NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, onInvokeEvent);